# Is the relation in 3NF?

Tags: database, normalization, 3nf

R(ABCD) with FD's

AB -> CD
BC -> D

I found this question in a book and it says the relation is in 2nf but not in 3nf.

I cant find any trivial dependencies and also no non prime attribute is functionally dependent on another non prime attribute then how come the relation is not in 3nf?

Should i consider BC as a non prime attribute too? Please help me understand the concept of 3NF

I have one more doubt

If the functional depenencies are

AB -> CD, C -> A, A -> C

Will the relation be in 3NF? or will it violate 2NF because A -> C shows that C is not fully functionally dependent on AB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain in simple words:

Condition for **Second normal form**:

> It is in first normal form
>
> All non-prime attributes are fully functional dependent on the super key

Condition for **Third normal form**:

> It is in second normal form
>
> All non-key attributes must depend only on super key

```
 Note:2NF allows non-prime attribute to depend on non-prime but 3NF does not allows it
```

In the given relation:
AB -> CD BC -> D

*AB* is a prime attribute

*C,D* are non-prime attribute

> It is not in Third normal form because,
> D is a non-prime attribute which is not dependent on super-key AB

So,it is in 2NF and not in 3NF

Hope,it helps

Comment: Thankyou @Lordferrous  

I have one more doubt  

If the functional depenencies are  

AB -> CD, 
C -> A, 
A -> C  

Will the relation be in 3NF? or will it violate 2NF because 

A -> C 

shows that C is not fully functionally dependent on AB?

Comment: It will not be in third normal form...you are right!!C is not fully functional dependent on A..so it violates 2NF